# ISAPI error when installing Shibboleth SP with IIS7

Tags: iis-7, shibboleth, isapi

i'm currently trying to install the Shibboleth Service Provider on IIS7 and getting the following error from the browser when browsing to

http : // 127.0.0.1/Shibboleth.sso/Status :

> **Shibboleth Error**
>
> ISAPI extension can only be invoked to process
>   Shibboleth protocol requests.Make sure the mapped file extension
>   doesn't match actual content.

Here's what i tried so far:

- Restarted the Shibboleth 2 Daemon service
- Restarted IIS from the interface and using iisreset
- Configured shibboleth2.xml with the correct site id and the correct name in the ISAPI tag

  ```
  <!-- ISAPI Settings. -->
  <ISAPI normalizeRequest="true" safeHeaderNames="true">
      <!--
      Maps IIS Instance ID values to the host scheme/name/port. The name is
      required so that the proper <Host> in the request map above is found without
      having to cover every possible DNS/IP combination the user might enter.
      -->
      <Site id="2" name="my_host_name/courses"/>
      <!--
      When the port and scheme are omitted, the HTTP request's port and scheme are used.
      If these are wrong because of virtualization, they can be explicitly set here to
      ensure proper redirect generation.
      -->
      <!--
      <Site id="42" name="virtual.example.org" scheme="https" port="443"/>
      -->
  </ISAPI>
  ```
- Made sure the Status Handler type contains ::1

  ```
      <!-- Status reporting service. -->
      <Handler type="Status" Location="/Status" acl="127.0.0.1 ::1"/>
  ```

Now from IIS
I added the ISAPI shibboleth dll in the ISAPI Filters

- Name=Shibboleth
- Executable=path/to/shibboleth-sp/lib64/shibboleth/isapi_shib.dll
- Entry Type=local

I added the same dll in the ISAPI and CGI Restrictions
Description

- Description=[No Description]
- Restriction=Allowed
- Path=path/to/shibboleth-sp/lib64/shibboleth/isapi_shib.dll

I made sure the hosts files contains the IP and my hostname.

I found some answers from Shibboleth forums with that error but nothing seems to be working.

If i disable the SSO i can browse the /course folder.
I can reach the same page with the error from another computer, not only from the server itself.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Which version of the Shibboleth service provider installed. Please Install the latest version 3.0.2.0. and please check the option IIS 7.0 while Installing. We faced the similar issue, after i upgraded to the version 3.0.2.0 it worked for us.